# Class not found error on Ubuntu but not on windows

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-sdk

I am trying to host my PHP web page I made on Windows 10 (Tested on 2 machines and it worked fine) on an Ubuntu machine, I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, php 8.1 on an apache server.
Error is the following: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\\IoTDataPlane\\IoTDataPlaneClient' not found in /home/Dioswilson/testPage/classes/AWSThing.php:32`

Here is the code in case you need it:

AWSThing.php (cropped)

```
<?php

namespace classes;

use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\IoTDataPlane\IoTDataPlaneClient;


class AwsThing  {
    private $thingName;
    private $userAccessKeyId;
    private $userSecretAccessKey;
    private $awsCredentials;
    private $shadow;
    private $client;

    public function __construct($thingName, $userAccessKeyId, $userSecretAccessKey) {
        $this->thingName = $thingName;
        $this->userAccessKeyId = $userAccessKeyId;
        $this->userSecretAccessKey = $userSecretAccessKey;
    }

    public function getShadow() {
        return $this->shadow;
    }

    public function authenticateAwsUser() {
        $this->awsCredentials = new Credentials(
            $this->userAccessKeyId,
            $this->userSecretAccessKey
        );
        $this->client = new IoTDataPlaneClient([
            'credentials' => $this->awsCredentials,
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest'
        ]);
    }
    //Cropped stuff from class......
}
```

I call this from index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"]) {
//    echo "Hello World";
} else {
    header("Location: login/login.php");
}
include "./classes/JardinThing.php";
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use classes\JardinThing;

$logoJardin = new JardinThing("ThingName", "key", "secret");  //Ofc this is censored
//More below, but it breaks here
?>
```

Project structure (On both windows and Ubuntu):

```
testPage
|
|-index.php
|->classes
|   |-AWSThing.php
|->vendor
    |->aws
        |->aws-sdk-php
            |->src
                |->IotDataPlane
                    |-IotDataPlane.php
```

Only thing that raised my attention was the path given by php which had "\", but i asumed it was just printing \ with the escpae code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `use Aws\IotDataPlane\IotDataPlaneClient` instead of `use Aws\IoTDataPlane\IoTDataPlaneClient` and then instantiate object with

```
$this->client = new IotDataPlaneClient([
            'credentials' => $this->awsCredentials,
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest'
        ]);
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Why did it work on windows and not on linux?

Comment: so everything is good, right?

Comment: You might first try to refer to the examples in the AWS documentation on how exactly it should be used.

Comment: Yes, everything good, thank you